# How do you attach an EventEmitter Output to a component under routing?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a route config

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Start', component: Journal },
    { path: '/register', name: 'Register', component: Register },
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: Login },
    { path: '/settings', name: 'Settings', component: Settings },
])
```

I'd like to listen to events emitted from Journal's @Output. How can I do that when the only reference I have in the template is

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" [routerLink]="['Journal']">Journal</a>
```

?

Comment: [You can't](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4452). You'll have to use a shared service.

Comment: Thanks - that's the direction I wound up going anyway

Comment: @EricMartinez Thnx for the link. This so frustrating. If you have nested routing there is simply no use for eventEmitters and all should be done with services! I am looking at integrating Redux, for this specific reason. Although I like Angular 2, it has its limits and should also consider integrating a Redux like philosophy. In my projects I tend to do already something like Redux, introducing services in the root folder and injecting them where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is pretty old now, but passing state to the route is undoable. This is mostly because `routerLink` is generic and could take *any number* of potential children. So even if you could pass state or process its events, you would end up with unneeded complexity.

The correct way to manage state between parent and child components, is a [shared service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service). Essentially, it comes down to these steps:

1. Write a service.
2. Provide the service not from your module, but from the parent component (to make it inaccessible to outside code).
3. Inject the service into the parent and any children that would need it.

This would work equally well with state passed into the child and with notifications received from the child and doesn't pollute the route setup.