# How to change parent variable from children component?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-components

This question is quite simple but I can't get rid of it.

I have a `<header>` in parent template and I need it disappear when displaying children template through routing module. What I expect is adding a class to the header tag so I can hide it via CSS. This is what I have:
**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <header [class.hidden]="hide">
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <ul>
            <li><a href="/home"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/showoff"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
  hide = false; // <-- This is what I need to change in child component
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './welcome.component';
import { ShowOffComponent } from './show.off.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'showoff', component: ShowOffComponent },
];

export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  useHash: true
});
```

**show.offf.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-showoff',
   template: `
       <h2>Show Off</h2>
       <div>Some contents...</div>
   `
})

export class ShowOffComponent {
   hide = true; // <-- Here is the problem.
                // I don't have any idea how to reach parent variables.
}
```

Comment: you can accept answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 20):

You can use [output emitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent)

In your child component,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-showoff',
   template: `
       <h2>Show Off</h2>
       <div>Some contents...</div>
   `
})

export class ShowOffComponent {
    @Output() onHide = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    setHide(){
       this.onHide.emit(true);
    }
}
```

In the parent,

```
export class AppComponent {
  hide = false;

  changeHide(val: boolean) {
    this.hide = val;
  }
}
```

Add a child to the parent with that event emitter,

```
<app-showoff (onHide)="changeHide($event)"></app-showoff>
```

Comment: and for more complex scenarios you can do a service ('LayoutService') and create there an EventEmitter, so wherever you want you can use this Event for any component.

Comment: right.. there are plenty of ways of parent child communication as per the docs depending on specific scenarios.

Comment: Thank you, but the `onHide()` argument on parent component does nothing in this case. I have tested it using simple alert on both `setHide()` and `onHide()`. When `(click)` handler triggered, only `setHide()` showing alert. And then I realize this can't be implemented using route module after I found [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878762/how-do-you-attach-an-eventemitter-output-to-a-component-under-routing).

Comment: ok.. so You need to use a common service. [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

Comment: Well, it works! But, to make the service working, it asked me to define `<app-showoff [onHide]="hide"></app-showoff>` inside **router-outlet** which is not great, as it will made the template still exist even when I change the route.Besides, using service is the way more complex to achieve this, since I just need to set a variable to true/false, not bi-directional communication.

Answer (score 9):

I have bumped into the same phenomena very recently with Angular 6.

I wanted to access and change a variable which is belongs to a parent or a grandparent Component. See the image below. I want to access and change a variable which is belongs to Tom, from Jim (who is a child of Tom) and Sara (who is a grandchild of Tom).

[image]

There might be some other solutions but the approach I have used to overcome this is by using `ViewContainerRef`. I have to inject the `ViewContainerRef` to the Child component's constructor, that I need to access the parent Component and traversed through the parent node (or nodes) to find the parent variable.

Injecting to the constructor,

```
constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
```

Accessing and traversing through to the parent node,

```
getParentComponent() {
    return this.viewContainerRef[ '_data' ].componentView.component.viewContainerRef[ '_view' ].component
}
```

I have made a StackBlitz example with the scenario that I have given you in the above picture.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-comms

Hope someone will find this useful.

Thank you.

Comment: I just ran into this issue, thanks for the fix! you saved me quite a bit of time!

Comment: @JacquesOlivier I am glad   you found my answer helpful :)

Comment: @AnjanaSilva It's not working angular 12. Kindly share here that solution. I have ```componentView undefined``` console error.

Answer (score 3):

In your `app.component.ts` you can check your URL and set `hide` variable value as below :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <header [class.hidden]="hide">
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <ul>
            <li><a href="/home"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/showoff"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
  hide = false; // <-- This is what I need to change in child component

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((events) => {
      if (events instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (events.url === '/' || events.url === '/home') {
          this.hide = false;
        } else {
          this.hide = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Less straightforward, but (imho) more accurate way to achieve this is to use service.

1. create parent-to-child.service.ts file and create a subject property

   export class ParentToChildService {
   showHeader = new Subject();
   }
2. inject it via a constructor in both parent and child components:

   constructor(private ptcService: ParentToChildService ) {}
3. Bind the header component with ngIf (or you can use ngClass, if you insist on using CSS approach) to the property in its TS file:

html: `<header *ngIf="showStatus">`
TS:   `showStatus: boolean = true;  // true by default ptcSubscription: Subscription;`

4. On ngInit of the header component subscribe to that subject:

   ngOnInit(): {
   this.ptcSubscription = this.ptcService.showHeader.subscribe(
   (newStatus: boolean) => {
   this.showStatus = newStatus
   });
   }
   );
   }
5. In your child component, whenever you need to hide the `<header`>, call `next` on the service subject:

   this.ptcService.showHeader.next(false);  //hiding the header